# Unity: How do I make a directional dash when double tapping a button

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am attempting to make a character do a quick small dash in the direction they are moving upon pressing a button twice. I have a override layer in my Animator and I a blend tree for all the directions of the dash. But I cannot seem to get this to work at all. I have spent about 4 hours trying to work this out myself, but I give up and could use some help or a direction.

Side Note: I am still pretty new to C# but have a ton of experience in LUA, so forgive me if there is a obvious oversight here I am still learning.

Code Below:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace DarkHaven
{


    public class InputManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private float doublePressTime = 0.25f;                               // Amount of time between presses to trigger
        private float lastPressTime = -10f;                                  // Resets value
        private float horizontal;
        private float vertical;

        Animator anim;

        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        {
            anim = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
            horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");


            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))                                 // B Button is pressed
            {
                float timeDelta = Time.time - lastPressTime;

                if(timeDelta < doublePressTime)
                {
                    anim.SetFloat("Vertical", vertical);
                    anim.SetFloat("Horizontal", horizontal);

                    lastPressTime = 0;

                    anim.CrossFade("Dash",0.2f);
                    Debug.Log("Cancel Sprint and perform Dash");
                }
                else
                {
                    lastPressTime = Time.time;
                   // anim.SetBool("IsSprinting", true);

                }
            }

            if (Input.GetButtonUp("Fire1"))
            {
                //anim.SetBool("IsSprinting", false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by a 'dash'?

Comment: like move foward very quickly.

Comment: Ok, as it is now, do the animations work the way you want them to? Does it go into the dash animation when you double tap the buttons? Does it also print "Cancel Sprint and perform Dash"?